# How to stretch an image to cover full width and height of the div? (Using Flexbox)

Tags: html, angularjs, css, flexbox

I want to adjust the size of the image to cover up the entire div. It would be very helpful if you guys can suggest anything in CSS rather than using javascript for it.

Here is a sample of what i have right now

```
.third{
  width:30%;
  float:left;
  margin:8px;
}

.second{
  display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
    -ms-flex-flow: row wrap;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
}
img{
  width:100%;
  object-fit:fill;
}

<div class="first">
  <div class="second">
    <div class="third">
      <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/nT8pKpXQSJY/maxresdefault.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="third">
      <img src="http://i1.wp.com/proyectart.es/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/One-Punch-Man.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="third">
      <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/nT8pKpXQSJY/maxresdefault.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="third">
      <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/nT8pKpXQSJY/maxresdefault.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="third">
      <img src="http://i1.wp.com/proyectart.es/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/One-Punch-Man.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="third">
      <img src="http://i1.wp.com/proyectart.es/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/One-Punch-Man.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the link to the codepen for more details: http://codepen.io/gruler05/pen/vGyObo

The first, third and the fourth images are smaller than the rest. Can anyone please tell me how can I stretch those image to the size of their container div so that it looks like all the images are of the same size. Thank you in advance. P.S: I tried object-fit but it didn't work.

Comment: You could set the images as background-images of the divs and use background-size:cover.

Comment: I thought about it but is there any other way I can do it without using the background-image?

Comment: Do you need the image itself to set the height/width?, which `background-image` don't, and does the images need to keep aspect ratio?

Comment: @LGSon it's fine if some of the images lose it's aspect ratio. Because i know there would only be like 3-4 out of 15 images which would be slightly less in height than others.

Comment: I posted an update, giving you some options.

Answer (score 1):

Using background-size:cover; in your CSS rules for the element is probably the easiest way to get full image coverage. This might cut off some of the content, though, depending on if you center the background image in the div or how you resize it.

background-size:contain; might be more useful, but I'm a huge fan of the cover size property.

**Update**

If you want to avoid background-image then you could try an img tag set to 100% width and/or height, but this will warp your image and cause other issues, and you'd potentially have to perform some JS calculations to prevent this.

Why the aversion to using a background image?

Comment: I am using ng-repeat to get the source of the images from the json file. Then i guess had to use it as an inline css property to set it as a background image and then loop through it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a few ways, depending on if you want stretch or clipped images.

In sample 1 and 2, the trick I used is to keep the `img` as `visibility: hidden` to not have to set a fixed height on the `third` div.

Also, using the inline style for the image url, you can easily make that work with angular without messing with the external CSS.

Sample 1 - stretched

```css
.third {
  flex: 1 0 calc(33% - 16px);
  margin: 8px;
  position: relative;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
.second{
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}
img {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="first">
  <div class="second">
    <div class="third" style="background-image: url( https://i.ytimg.com/vi/nT8pKpXQSJY/maxresdefault.jpg)">
        <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/nT8pKpXQSJY/maxresdefault.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="third" style="background-image: url(http://i1.wp.com/proyectart.es/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/One-Punch-Man.jpg)">
      <img src="http://i1.wp.com/proyectart.es/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/One-Punch-Man.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="third" style="background-image: url( https://i.ytimg.com/vi/nT8pKpXQSJY/maxresdefault.jpg)">
        <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/nT8pKpXQSJY/maxresdefault.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="third" style="background-image: url( https://i.ytimg.com/vi/nT8pKpXQSJY/maxresdefault.jpg)">
        <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/nT8pKpXQSJY/maxresdefault.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="third" style="background-image: url(http://i1.wp.com/proyectart.es/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/One-Punch-Man.jpg)">
      <img src="http://i1.wp.com/proyectart.es/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/One-Punch-Man.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="third" style="background-image: url(http://i1.wp.com/proyectart.es/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/One-Punch-Man.jpg)">
      <img src="http://i1.wp.com/proyectart.es/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/One-Punch-Man.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Sample 2 - clipped, center aligned

```css
.third {
  flex: 1 0 calc(33% - 16px);
  margin: 8px;
  position: relative;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
.second{
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}
img {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="first">
  <div class="second">
    <div class="third" style="background-image: url( https://i.ytimg.com/vi/nT8pKpXQSJY/maxresdefault.jpg)">
        <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/nT8pKpXQSJY/maxresdefault.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="third" style="background-image: url(http://i1.wp.com/proyectart.es/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/One-Punch-Man.jpg)">
      <img src="http://i1.wp.com/proyectart.es/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/One-Punch-Man.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="third" style="background-image: url( https://i.ytimg.com/vi/nT8pKpXQSJY/maxresdefault.jpg)">
        <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/nT8pKpXQSJY/maxresdefault.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="third" style="background-image: url( https://i.ytimg.com/vi/nT8pKpXQSJY/maxresdefault.jpg)">
        <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/nT8pKpXQSJY/maxresdefault.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="third" style="background-image: url(http://i1.wp.com/proyectart.es/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/One-Punch-Man.jpg)">
      <img src="http://i1.wp.com/proyectart.es/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/One-Punch-Man.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="third" style="background-image: url(http://i1.wp.com/proyectart.es/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/One-Punch-Man.jpg)">
      <img src="http://i1.wp.com/proyectart.es/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/One-Punch-Man.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Sample 3 - clipped, center aligned, fixed height (removed the `img` as well)

```css
.third {
  flex: 1 0 calc(33% - 16px);
  margin: 8px;
  position: relative;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  height: 150px;
}
.second{
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}
img {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="first">
  <div class="second">
    <div class="third" style="background-image: url( https://i.ytimg.com/vi/nT8pKpXQSJY/maxresdefault.jpg)">
    </div>
    <div class="third" style="background-image: url(http://i1.wp.com/proyectart.es/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/One-Punch-Man.jpg)">
    </div>
    <div class="third" style="background-image: url( https://i.ytimg.com/vi/nT8pKpXQSJY/maxresdefault.jpg)">
    </div>
    <div class="third" style="background-image: url( https://i.ytimg.com/vi/nT8pKpXQSJY/maxresdefault.jpg)">
    </div>
    <div class="third" style="background-image: url(http://i1.wp.com/proyectart.es/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/One-Punch-Man.jpg)">
    </div>
    <div class="third" style="background-image: url(http://i1.wp.com/proyectart.es/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/One-Punch-Man.jpg)">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adjusting your .third, it has a default padding that you can remove by adding the below CSS. You can adjust the height to however much you need. This way you can avoid background-image, but background-image would still be most efficient.

```
.third {
  width: 33.33%;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, but it will lose the image's aspect ratio.

HTML: Add a div with class="row" and put 3 images inside each

```html
<div class="first">
  <div class="second">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="third">
      <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/nT8pKpXQSJY/maxresdefault.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="third">
      <img src="http://i1.wp.com/proyectart.es/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/One-Punch-Man.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="third">
      <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/nT8pKpXQSJY/maxresdefault.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="third">
      <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/nT8pKpXQSJY/maxresdefault.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="third">
      <img src="http://i1.wp.com/proyectart.es/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/One-Punch-Man.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="third">
      <img src="http://i1.wp.com/proyectart.es/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/One-Punch-Man.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS: add the following code to give the .row a fixed height and set the image height to 95%

```css
.row{
 height:150px; //whatever height you want
}

.third img{
 height:95%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First delete all the `<img>` tags
then use this css

```
.third{
  width:290px;
  height:180px;
  float:left;
  margin:8px;
  background-image:url("https://i.ytimg.com/vi/nT8pKpXQSJY/maxresdefault.jpg");
  background-size:cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although flexbox is a great approach, The most easiest approach to do it by using tables, and inserting the images as data.
Here is the code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Images</title>
</head>
<body>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>    <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/nT8pKpXQSJY/maxresdefault.jpg" width="200" height="200"></td>
 
   <td>   <img src="http://i1.wp.com/proyectart.es/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/One-Punch-Man.jpg"  width="200" height="200"> </td>
 
    <td>  <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/nT8pKpXQSJY/maxresdefault.jpg"   width="200" height="200"> </td>
  </tr> 
  
  <tr>
    <td>   <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/nT8pKpXQSJY/maxresdefault.jpg"  width="200" height="200"> </td>
 
     <td> <img src="http://i1.wp.com/proyectart.es/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/One-Punch-Man.jpg"  width="200" height="200"> </td>
  
   <td>   <img src="http://i1.wp.com/proyectart.es/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/One-Punch-Man.jpg"  width="200" height="200"> </td>
  </tr> 
  
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```